# python import within import

Tags: python, import

i am trying to import a module within a module and then access the lower level module from the top, however it is not available. is this normal behaviour?

```
# caller.py
import first
print second.some_var

# first.py
import second

# second.py
some_var = 1
```

running `caller.py` gives error

```
NameError: name 'second' is not defined
```

do i have to `import second` within `caller.py`? this seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Circular imports can lead to annoying problems, so it would be better to avoid this kind of import pattern. If both `first` and `second` need access to `some_var`, you could create `third` module and put `some_var` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
import first
print first.second.some_var
```

Having `second` appear in the namespace automatically just by importing `first` would lead to lots of conflicts

This would also work

```
from first import second
print second.some_var
```

The use of wildcard

```
from first import *
```

is discouraged because if someone adds extra attributes/functions to `first` they may overwrite attributes you are using locally if they happen to choose the same name

Comment: thanks for explaining why the wildcard is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

`import first` will import the name `first` into the global namespace, but it does not import everything from `first` into the namespace.  So you can do one of the following:

- Access `second` through `first`:

  ```
  import first
  print first.second.some_var
  ```
- Import `second` directly into the namespace of caller.py:

  ```
  from first import second
  print second.some_var
  ```

Note that you can use `from first import *` to import all of the names from `first` into the namespace, but this is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

instead use:

```
from first import second
print first.second.some_var
```

It is a lot more compressed too. Why are you doing your way anyway?

Comment: basically i have common library files which i use in a lot of projects (many files with the role of 'second' in this example) and then i have higher level library files per project (ie many files with the role of 'first' in this example). so each project only needs to know about 'first', and 'first' only needs to know about 'second'. i know a class structure with `first extends second` would be ideal, but i'm just trying to see if i can use modules and avoid classes...